# How to change time unit from seconds to days/months/years

Tags: java, temporal

I am bashing my head against Java's Temporal API.  I can't find anything in the Java Docs or anywhere else that'll answer what I need to do.  I simply need to at 1,000,000,000 seconds to a date and return the date, calculating the moment someone lived a billion seconds (somewhere around 30 years.)

```java
    public Temporal getGigasecondDate(Temporal given) {
        final long gigasecond = 1000000000;
        final long gigaDays = gigasecond / 60 / 60 / 24;

        Duration amount = Duration.ofDays(gigaDays);

        Temporal date = amount.addTo(given);

        return date;
    }
```

I get an error saying `Exception in thread "main" java.time.DateTimeException: Unit must be Years, Months or Days, but was Seconds` and I can't for the life of me find a way in the JavaDocs, or anywhere else, figure out how to get the unit to years, months, or days.

All I need to do, is return a Temporal object that states the moment someone has lived a billion seconds.

Comment: Did you mean `return given.plus(1_000_000_000, ChronoUnit.SECONDS);`?

Comment: If you're interested in the _moment_ when someone has lived a billion seconds, wouldn't returning a `LocalDateTime` (or even an `Instant`) be more suitable?

Comment: @MickMnemonic For a moment, a specific point on the timeline, use `ZonedDateTime` or `Instant`. Do *not* `LocalDateTime` as it lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC, so cannot represent a moment.

Comment: @BasilBourque, yes, my main point was that `Temporal` is really hard to work with (and error prone) in client code because it's overly generic.

Comment: @MickMnemonic Yes, good, I just wanted to remedy that common misconception spread around on StackOverflow. Your other related comment about the [*Liskov substitution principle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) is well-taken.

Comment: Are we allowed to assume that the moment of gigasecond age is to be expressed in the same timezone as the moment of birth?

Answer (score 4):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime.of(                         // Mom gave birth at 3 AM in year 2000, New Zealand time.
    2000 , 1 , 23 , 3 , 45 , 0 , 0 , ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" )  
)                                         // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
.plus(
    Duration.ofSeconds( 1_000_000_000L )  // A billion seconds.
)                                         // Returns another `ZonedDateTime` object. Immutable objects in *java.time* means we get a fresh object rather than “mutating” (altering) the original.
.toString()                               // Generate a `String` representing the value of our `ZonedDateTime` object, using standard ISO 8601 format wisely extended to append the name of the time zone in square brackets.
```

> 2031-10-01T05:31:40+13:00[Pacific/Auckland]

## Details

The [Answer by Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51295104/642706) is correct. Here are a few more thoughts.

## Do not use `Temporal`

The documentation for *java.time* explains that generally in an app you should be using the concrete classes rather than the interfaces and superclasses. To quote from [`Temporal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/temporal/Temporal.html) interface:

> This interface is a framework-level interface that should not be widely used in application code. Instead, applications should create and pass around instances of concrete types, such as LocalDate. There are many reasons for this, part of which is that implementations of this interface may be in calendar systems other than ISO. See ChronoLocalDate for a fuller discussion of the issues.

## Adding a billion seconds to a birth-moment

> [add] 1,000,000,000 seconds to a date and return the date,

Determine the moment of the person's birth.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2000 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ;
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( 3 , 45 ) ;  // Mom gave birth at 3 AM in New Zealand time.
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt , z ) ;
```

See that same moment in UTC, if useful.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

Define the amount of time to add. The `Duration` class represents a span of time not attached to the timeline.

```
Duration d = Duration.ofSeconds( 1_000_000_000L ) ;
```

Add.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtLater = zdt.plus( d ) ;
```

Or, in UTC (same moment, different wall-clock time).

```
Instant instantLater = instant.plus( d ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://www.ideone.com/gC2ecO).

> zdt.toString(): 2000-01-23T03:45+13:00[Pacific/Auckland]
>
> instant.toString(): 2000-01-22T14:45:00Z
>
> d.toString(): PT277777H46M40S
>
> zdtLater.toString(): 2031-10-01T05:31:40+13:00[Pacific/Auckland]
>
> instantLater.toString(): 2031-09-30T16:31:40Z

If you care for only the date, without the time-of-day and without the time zone, extract a `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate ldLater = zdtLater.toLocalDate() ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call [`plus(long amountToAdd, TemporalUnit unit)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/Temporal.html#plus-long-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-), with unit as [`ChronoUnit.SECONDS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#SECONDS):

```
public static Temporal getGigasecondDate(Temporal given) {
    return given.plus(1_000_000_000, ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(getGigasecondDate(LocalDateTime.of(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0)));
System.out.println(getGigasecondDate(ZonedDateTime.of(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("America/New_York"))));
```

*Output*

```
2031-09-09T01:46:40
2031-09-09T02:46:40-04:00[America/New_York]
```

So, someone born at midnight on Jan 1, 2000 will be 1 billion seconds old on Sep 9, 2031 at 1:46:40 AM, assuming no Daylight Savings Time.

If they lived in New York, it would be at 2:46:40 AM EDT.

Comment: But if they are [Thai Buddhist](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/ThaiBuddhistDate.html), you'll get `java.time.temporal.UnsupportedTemporalTypeException: Unsupported unit: Seconds` with `System.out.println(getGigasecondDate(ThaiBuddhistDate.of(2000, 1, 1)));`. Just pointing out the problems involved with using the `Temporal` interface from the Liskov substitution principle point of view.